# Using google speech recognition on android wear without showing specific ui

Tags: android, speech-recognition, wear-os

This is my first question here on stackoverflow, so sorry if i am doing something wrong.
I have an app on android wear, where the user shall select an item from a list.

I want to enable the user to select the item via voice commands. I managed to do it as suggested in the [google documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/voice.html), but i have to implement a button to start speech recognition, and it will show up as a fullscreen activity.

I want the user to be able to see the list while speech recognition is active. Is there any solution for this?

EDIT: I might have found the solution i was looking for. It is the speech recognizer, which seems to be able to do just what i want. I will have to dig into that and will update this post if it is the solution.